# Is it possible to create a python documentation when there are no classes?

Tags: python

I have many python files.

Each file has functions. That's it.  I don't do anything with classes.

Will Sphinx (or another documentation software) still create the documentation for it, and if so, what will it look like?

Comment: Did you *try* it? It would probably be quicker than asking on here!

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. But why no classes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. That's one of the many normal ways to program in Python. You don't have to use classes -- in fact, many of the modules that come with Python are just collections of functions. Any Python documentation tool will be prepared to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, Python functions and classes are all documented in a specific way that the language (and documentation-generating software) can see, called a docstring. If you put a string immediately after every function definition, like this:

```
def double(number):
    """Returns number times 2. May behave poorly if number isn't actually a number"""
    return number * 2;
```

...then you can get the function `double`'s docstring from `double.__doc__`.

For a more detailed description of how to write good docstrings, see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Search for "Documentation Strings" to skip to the part you care about.